# How can I accomplish IRenderedComponent.FindComponent<DxTextBox>("#myid")

Tags: bunit

In bUnit I want to make a call like this:

```
var textbox = renderedComponent.FindComponent<DxTextBox>("#myid");
```

However, `FindComponent<T>()` does not have a method that accepts any filtering. Is there any way to do this other than call `IRenderedComponent.FindComponents<DxTextBox>()` and then walk the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no, there is no other way (at the moment).
You could write your own extension method to achieve that (just a rough outline, I did not test that code):

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T FindComponentWithSelector<T>(this IRenderedFragment renderedFragment, string selector) where T : IComponent
    {
        var elements = renderedFragment.FindAll(selector);
        
        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            var component = renderedFragment.FindComponent<T>(element);
            if (component != null)
            {
                return component.Instance;
            }
        }
        
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Component of type {typeof(T).FullName} with selector '{selector}' not found.");
    }
    
    private static IRenderedComponent<TComponent>? FindComponent<TComponent>(this IRenderedFragment renderedFragment, IElement element) 
        where TComponent : IComponent
    {
        return renderedFragment.FindComponents<TComponent>()
            .FirstOrDefault(component => component.Markup.Contains(element.OuterHtml, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

We have this on our radar to some extent: https://github.com/bUnit-dev/bUnit/issues/153

This would allow you to retrieve the `IRenderedComponent` from an `IElement`.